# HTML tabindex on <a> with children

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabindex

I have a toggling navigation menu structured the following way:

```
<li>
  <a href="mylink.page">
    <span class="text">Link Text</span>
    <span tabindex="0" class="button"></span>
  </a>
  <ul>... children ... </ul>
</li>
```

span.text houses the link text and span.button is the element that a user can click or keypress enter to toggle the nested ul.

While tabbing through the menu (testing accessibility), my browser (tried in both latest public versions of Chrome and Firefox on Windows) focuses on the container a, then focuses on span.text, then finally on span.button. This is the behavior I want but don't want the container 'a' to get focused on - just go straight to span.text.

Note: When focused on container 'a', hitting enter does not activate the link, only the children spans activate the link when focused upon (I have prevented the link from working when keypress enter on span.button so the toggling works on keypress enter).

This behavior is fine and is essentially how I want it (spans being the links activated by keypress enter) expect I want to skip the container 'a' when tabbing and go straight to the children spans.

tabindex="-1" right? Nope. When adding tabindex="-1" to the container 'a', span.text no longer gets focused and an active link is gone. The browser focuses on the container 'a' and then skips over span.text to span.button. This is odd (at least to me). In my mind, tabindex="-1" is used for skipping the element while tabbing.

Any ideas how I can use tabindex on a combination of the container 'a' and the children spans to achieve what I stated above (tabbing through menu only hits span.name [which has active link] and span.button)? Or even a javascript/jquery solution?

Note: Having tabindex="0" seems to be the only way to tab to span.button.

EDIT: After tinkering for a bit, I put tabindex="0" on the container 'a' and it works beautifully in Chrome. Firefox still focuses on the container 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, try:

```
$('a:has(span[tabindex])').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).find('span[tabindex]').focus();
}).on('keypress', 'span[tabindex]', function (e) {
    if(e.which === 13) { 
       this.click(); //this not $(this), to call native click method
       //or: $(this).parent()[0].click();
    }
});
```

For jQuery below 1.7, try:

```
$('a:has(span[tabindex])').bind('focus', function () {
    $(this).find('span[tabindex]')[0].focus(); // call js focus(), not jq
}).delegate('span[tabindex]', 'keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        this.click(); //this not $(this), to call native click method
        //or: $(this).parent()[0].click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Getting TypeError: $(...).on is not a function (line 1)

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? `.on()` was added in jq 1.7

Comment: Good question about jquery version. I am using 1.5 (and have to use 1.5 - a bit sandboxed during this). Your non-on() version works after I modified it a bit as it was skipping to the last span. $('a:has(span[tabindex])').bind('focus', function () {
        $(this).find('span.text').focus();
    });

Comment: Maybe try using: `$(this).find('span[tabindex]')[0].focus();` see updated answer. But any reson to not upgrade jQuery to newer version?

Comment: Using your edit along with modifying line 2 to find('span.text').focus() it works in Chrome but Firefox still focuses on the <a>. Might just be a Firefox issue.

Comment: I've tested it on chrome, FF & IE11, all work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/wg6LLc2o/  Note: this is `$(this).find('span[tabindex]')[0].focus();` not `$(this).find('span[tabindex]').focus();`

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. Maybe you're misunderstanding what I'm after. I want both children spans to be traversable via tab. Your solution skips the first span.

Comment: Thank you for your continued updates. Looks like it is indeed working in Firefox, according to jsfiddle. So I'm going to blame the issues I'm having in Firefox to personal issues rather than spec issues or issues with your solution. Since this is 99% working on my end (100% right overall), I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks so much for your help. It is truly appreciated!